# Cannot change color of message displayed by a simple logger in a reliable manner

Tags: node.js, colors, console.log

Hi I'm having some trouble colouring some console.log messages as part of node.js scripts I'm writing, does anyone has a hint ? See below the code that summarises the point:

```
"use strict"; 

const colors=require("colors");
const sprintf = require('sprintf-js').sprintf

class LOGGER {
    constructor() {
    }

    log(msg) {
        console.log.apply(console,arguments);
    }

    error1(...msg) {
       console.log.apply(console, ["\x1b[33m", ...msg,"\x1b[0m"]);
    }

    error2(...msg) {
        console.log(colors.yellow(...msg));
    }
    error3(...msg) {
        console.log(colors.red(sprintf(...msg)));
    }
}

const logger = new LOGGER();

logger.log("Here are my parameters:","P1","P2");
logger.log("Here are my parameters: %s %s","P1","P2");
logger.error1("Here are my parameters:","P1","P2");
logger.error2("Here are my parameters:","P1","P2");
logger.error3("Here are my parameters:","P1","P2");

logger.error1("Here are my parameters: %s %s","P1","P2");
logger.error2("Here are my parameters: %s %s","P1","P2");
logger.error3("Here are my parameters: %s %s","P1","P2");
```

- Running this above with node v10.5.0 leads to (need to run it to have the real colours):

```
Here are my parameters: P1 P2
Here are my parameters: P1 P2
 Here are my parameters: P1 P2 
Here are my parameters: P1 P2
Here are my parameters:
 Here are my parameters: %s %s P1 P2 
Here are my parameters: %s %s P1 P2
Here are my parameters: P1 P2
```

- So far I have no satisfactory solution so any idea on how to get that done would be greatly appreciated. In fact something like color that would return an array of arguments rather than a string so that invoking:

```
console.log.apply(console,colorThatReturnAnArrayOfArguments(...msg));
```

if do-able would probably be ideal but I have not figured out how to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

I actually did some more investigation and decided to try the following option which consist in letting first console.log to do its formatting job by writing to a stream and then to colour the result.

```
"use strict"; 

const colors=require("colors");
const { Console } = require('console');
const { Writable } = require('stream');

const outStream = new Writable({
  write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    console.log(colors.red(chunk.toString().replace(/\n$/, "")));
    callback();
  }
});

const myCons = new Console(outStream);

class LOGGER {
    constructor() {
    }

    log(msg) {
        console.log.apply(console,arguments);
    }

    error4(...msg) {
        myCons.log.apply(myCons,arguments);
    }
}

const logger = new LOGGER();

logger.log("Here are my parameters:","P1","P2");
logger.log("Here are my parameters: %s %s","P1","P2");

logger.error4("Here are my parameters:","P1","P2");
logger.error4("Here are my parameters: %s %s","P1","P2");
```